# How to send objects to a servlet from a submit form

Tags: forms, servlets, gwt

I'm currently working on a GWT project and have a form with enctype multipart/form-data to upload a document. To receive the submit request, I have a servlet in the server side.

Now, I want to send an array of objects at the same time as sending the document with the submit form. The problem is that all information I want to send through the submit form, I need to put in a form field somehow ...

I first thought of creating inputs programmatically with an iteration over the array of objects. However, I just cannot put an entire object in a TextBox ...

I'm probably missing something very simple ...

Thanks for your help !

Comment: probably you need some hidden fields

Comment: That's what I've been trying but as I said, I don't know how to create a form structure to fit all the attributes of all the objects I want to send ...

Comment: @HyukchanKwon i suggest providing a sample code (object structure, Gwt sample) of what you have tried so far so its easier for some one looking at this to understand what you are trying and thus respond with useful suggestions.